# Cannot resolve native module with ElectronJS

Tags: webpack, electron, pcap, resolve, native-module

I've started an ElectronJS/React/Typescript project including the pcap module. Unfortunately, this module requires a native dependency (pcap_binding.node).
I've already overridden the webpack configuration using `react-app-rewired` by creating the file `config-overrides.js`.
So far, I tried the following loaders: `native-ext-loader`, `@marshallofsound/webpack-asset-relocator-loader`, `@zeit/webpack-asset-relocator-loader`, and `node-loader`.
Epic fail. I still got the error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './build/Release/pcap_binding' in '/mnt/Data/Dropbox/DTI/Developement/asterix_flux_transporter/node_modules/pcap'
```

My Electron web preferences are:

```js
webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    contextIsolation: false,
    enableRemoteModule: true
}
```

and I also override webpack configuration with `target: "electron-renderer"`.

Og course, if I use the same code on terminal without ElectronJS, that is to say only NodeJS, everything is running fine...

How can I get rid of that error? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use native node moudles using electron, you just need to make the calls from the main process and communicate with the frontend. Read about [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) in electron.